# Remove part of path for webpack5 asset modules

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I am setting up Webpack 5 and currently configuring asset management of static images that I would like to copy over from my src folder to my dist folder. I would like to keep the file structure of my /img folder in place as it copies over to the dist folder, but the issue I am running into is where I am trying to remove part of the path placeholder. Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

I have my rule as follows:

```
  {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
            filename: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]',
        }
  },
```

However when the file gets copied over, because I have the [path] placeholder as part of the name, the files will resemble /src/img/[name].[extension]?[hash]. I would like to keep the rest of the path intact as some of the images have paths like /src/img/favicons/[name].[extension]?[hash] and I feel that the dist folder should maintain this structure. The end goal would be to have the 2 files mentioned above not have the /src part of the file name included in this path.